# Facing Kubernetes CrashLoopBack

Tags: python, kubernetes, deployment, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy a Python Api on Google Kubernetes Engine. But when I check `kubectl get pods`, it gave me "crashloopback off error".

Can anybody guide me what is error and why it is occurring

[image]

Comment: The process inside the pod is exiting fairly promptly.  That's about all that can be told from what you've provided.  (Please don't paste screen shots of terminals or IDEs into SO questions, they can be hard to read and aren't searchable.)

Answer (score 1):

Since first it says `Error`, then `CrashLoopBackOff`, probably your app is crashing inside the container, so you are getting the `Error`, then the pod dies, since there are no processes running inside it. But as you have a deployment behind it, it re-creates the pod, so you are in a loop.

Describing the pod probably won't give you anything, as the error is because of the app.

Logs, on the other hand, will tell you what's going on. If you get the logs right after the pod gets created it will tell you what's failing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Receive and read the logs:

```
kubectl logs po/tens-app-5844fd978f-95jxl
```

2) Describe you pod:

```
kubectl describe po/tens-app-5844fd978f-95jxl
```

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the Resource availability in the cluster.You can find the reason using one of these kubectl logs / kubectl describe.

Also try using Resource request and limits in your yaml (numbers are just example):

resources:
            requests:
            memory: "5000Mi"
            cpu: "1"
          limits:
            memory: "8000Mi"
            cpu: "2"